# How to allow only integer numbers in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, validation, input, numbers, integer

I have a number input in my HTML and I want it to be an integer, not a floating point number.

So, if I have this:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="person.age" />
```

Angular will consider a value of **18.4** to be valid. How can I fix this?

Comment: use ng-pattern to this. ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/"

Comment: @hadiJZ - seems like a good idea. Can you help me with the exact regex that I need?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```js
function Main($scope) {

     $scope.regex = "/^-?[0-9][^\.]*$/";
   }
```

```css
input.ng-dirty.ng-invalid { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Main">
        <form name="form">
   <input type="number" ng-model="person.age" ng-pattern="/^-?[0-9][^\.]*$/"/>
           <input type="number" ng-model="person.age1" ng-pattern="{{regex}}" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

try this

```
 $scope.regex = "/^-?[0-9][^\.]*$/";

<input type="number" ng-model="person.age" ng-pattern="{{regex}}"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think it's working pretty well. Thanks, man. I will test it and when I am sure that everything's correct, I will choose your answer as best.

Comment: It does not allow negative values now.

Comment: One last thing so far. The regex considers a value like "16." or "0." to be valid. How to exclude the "." (dot) also?

Comment: I run the code snippet and it's working perfectly, but it's not working the same in my app. In fact, it still allows dots and in doesn't work with a scope variable, only with a regex expression typed directly into the ng-pattern attribute. Maybe this has something to do with the Angular versions. I'm using 1.4.6

Comment: With this "0123123123" your "/^-?[0-9][^\.]*$/" won't work. Also you will be able to enter "+" and "." signs

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this `ng-pattern="/^(0|\-?[1-9][0-9]*)$/"`.

Answer (score 2):

I will share part of my code. 
In my **.ts file** I have the following code:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
...
export class IntegerComponent implements OnInit {
fgInteger: FormGroup;
...
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fgInteger = this.formBuilder.group({
      amount: ['', [Validators.required, ..., Validators.pattern('^\\d+$')]]
    });
  }
}
```

The pattern into the **.ts** worked for me:

- **'^'** This is the start of the pattern.
- **'\d'** This means that the value is a **digit** (0-9).
- **'+'** Means that this pattern should be used more than 1 time.
- **'$'** This is the end of the pattern.

Also, into my **.html file**, I have the following code:

```
<form id="fgInteger" [formGroup]="fgInteger" novalidate #fform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Amount:</mat-label>
          <input name="amount" formControlName="amount" type="number" min="1" step="1" matInput placeholder="Enter the amount.">
     </mat-form-field>
 </form>
```

By the way I'm working with **Angular Material**.

Comment: This didn't really answer the question of how to do it in Angular. This would be how to do it in standard HTML.

Comment: You are right! So, I will update my answer.

Comment: My answer was updated!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
<input type="number" step="1" min="0">
```

Comment: the problem of this is that you can still manually enter something like 18.4

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option that works great for me. It doesn't allow the user to enter non integer values, but intercepts the keyboard entries if invalid and prevents the character from being typed.

```
<input type="number" min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" maxlength="3" placeholder="Quantity"/>
```